# finding peaks in audio signal using numpy and scipy

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I'm just learning to work with numpy and scipy with python, i want to work with audio waveforms and play with them.

i'm fetching audio data from an mp3, i get it with a raange of  -1 to +1, i convert it to -255 to +255,

now i read on google, on cookbooks and stackoverflow and ilm trying to see the difference between type of pick detections that i can use using `scipy.signal.findpeeks`, the problem is that is finds almost all the dots as the peaks, i'm missing something.

this are the params of peaks that i'm trying to use:

```
peaks, _ = find_peaks(data, distance=25)
peaks2, _ = find_peaks(data, prominence=1)      # BEST!
peaks3, _ = find_peaks(data, width=20)
peaks4, _ = find_peaks(data, threshold=0.4)
```

and this is the result of displaying all the peaks:

[image: showing only peaks]

and this is the full code:

```
import av
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.signal import find_peaks, find_peaks_cwt, argrelextrema, argrelmax, argrelmin
from scipy.ndimage.filters import gaussian_filter1d


container = av.open(
    'free.mp3')

data = np.empty(shape=0)

for packet in container.demux():
    for frame in packet.decode():
        if isinstance(frame, av.audio.frame.AudioFrame):
            layout = frame.layout
            channels = layout.channels
            (chl, chr) = channels
            print(frame,
                  frame.format,
                  frame.layout,
                  frame.rate,
                  frame.samples)
            print(chl, chr)
            array = frame.to_ndarray()[0]
            data = np.concatenate([data, array])
data = np.interp(data, [-1, 1], [-255, 255])
peaks, _ = find_peaks(data, distance=25)
peaks2, _ = find_peaks(data, prominence=1)      # BEST!
peaks3, _ = find_peaks(data, width=20)
peaks4, _ = find_peaks(data, threshold=0.4)     # Required vertical distance to its direct neighbouring samples, pretty useless

plt.subplot(2, 2, 1)
plt.plot(peaks, data[peaks], "xr");
#plt.plot(data);
plt.legend(['distance'])
plt.subplot(2, 2, 2)
plt.plot(peaks2, data[peaks2], "ob");

#plt.plot(data); plt.legend(['prominence'])

plt.subplot(2, 2, 3)
plt.plot(peaks3, data[peaks3], "vg");

#plt.plot(data);

plt.legend(['width'])

plt.subplot(2, 2, 4)
plt.plot(peaks4, data[peaks4], "xk");
#plt.plot(data);

plt.legend(['threshold'])

plt.plot(data)
plt.legend(['cwt'])
plt.grid()
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

what am I missing ?

any information regarding this issue would be greatly appreciated
thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify multiple parameters

```
scipy.signal.find_peaks(x, height=None, threshold=None, distance=None, prominence=None, width=None, wlen=None, rel_height=0.5, plateau_size=None)
```

That's the documentation for your function, and so you need to specify a combination of parameters that works for your signal in questin.